# Cannot install Hangfire to my existing project

Tags: asp.net, hangfire

I have an existing ASP.NET project and it's not in MVC. When I try to install Hangire I get this error.

```
PM> Install-Package Hangfire
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Hangfire.1.5.8' with respect to project 'FYMAS', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Hangfire.1.5.8' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'Hangfire.1.5.8'
Resolved actions to install package 'Hangfire.1.5.8'
Adding package 'Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.1' to folder 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\hang\packages'
Added package 'Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.1' to folder 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\hang\packages'
Added package 'Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.1' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.1' to FYMAS
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Hangfire.Core.1.5.8 : Newtonsoft.Json [5.0.0, ), Owin [1.0.0, )' does not exist in project 'FYMAS'
Removed package 'Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.1' from 'packages.config'
Package 'Hangfire.Core.1.5.8 : Newtonsoft.Json [5.0.0, ), Owin [1.0.0, )' does not exist in folder 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\hang\packages'
Removing package 'Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.1' from folder 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\hang\packages'
Removed package 'Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.1' from folder 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\hang\packages'
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Hangfire.Core 1.5.8'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package 
does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Hangfire
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

I tried to install owin to my project using `Install-Package Owin` command, this installation is success but when I try to install hanfire again, I got the same error. I tried installing an older version of hangfire using `Install-Package HangFire -Version 1.4.6`, but got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your problem is your .NET framework, you are using 4.0, then you should install hangfire for your framework, try this

```
Install-Package Hangfire_net40
```

When you use `Install-Package Hangfire`, this will install the latest stable version (in your case Hangfire.1.5.8, this requires newer .net framework  ~ 4.5). For more details,  [Hangfire (.Net 4.0) 1.1.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hangfire_net40/)

Comment: this installed the hangfire but I cannot follow along with this [blog](http://frankouimette.com/tutorial-installing-hangfire-without-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: you have to create AccountStatusJob class and Execute method